# sqlite - copy subset of tables and columns into new db-file

Tags: sqlite

I have a database `A.db`, which contains tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.
Now I want to create a new database `B.db`, which contains `t1` and some chosen columns `col1` and `col4` from `t2`.

With `.import` I get hundreds of errors and it seems to work only for full tables.

`.output` sounds like I just save the output as it would be printed.

Basically, I need an `insert into foo select ...` across different files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must attach `A.db` to your current database and give it an alias like `adb`.
Then write the insert statement just like you would if all the tables existed in the same database, qualifying the column names with the database alias.
It's a good practice to include in the `insert into...` statement inside parentheses all the column names of the table `foo` for which you will set values from the other 2 tables, but also be sure that the order of the columns is the same with the order of the columns in the select list:

```
attach database 'pathtoAdatabase/A.db' as adb;

insert into foo (column1, column2, .......)
select adb.t1.column1, adb.t1.column2, ...., adb.t2.col1, adb.t2.col4
from adb.t1 inner join adb.t2
on <join condition>
```

Replace `<join condition>` with the conditions on whichyou will join the 2 tables to makes the rows that you will insert into `foo`, something like:

```
adb.t1.id = adb.t2.id
```